# IMAP python - proper method of storing user authorization data

Tags: python, django, imap

I am working on an email client powered by Django and [IMAPClient library](http://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/master/).
On the client-side, users have interface for associating their mailboxes (like `test1@gmail.com`, `test2@gmail.com`, etc...) with their accounts in my app . And the goal is to store credentials info so that the user has to go through the procedure of inserting password and host name (like `imap.gmail.com`) only once unless he deliverately logs out from an account.

The question is, where and how should the login/password/hostname data used for establishing IMAP connection be stored? Is it my server's DB? Or some sort of `.ini` files? I remember, reading a post about python/imap where they stored it in `.ini` files, but I can't find it now.

Currently, I store credentials and IMAP hostname info in my local db. Thus, in each view that needs to fetch info from IMAP server, I query my server db to get the data and After this, I initialize IMAPClient variable for establishing connection with the IMAP server. And I have a terrible feeling that this is junk code:

```
def show_mail(request, login):
    user_email_info = UserEmailInfo.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id,
                                                login = login)
    HOST = user_email_info.host #'imap.gmail.com'
    USERNAME = user_email_info.login
    PASSWORD = user_email_info.psw 
    server = IMAPClient(HOST, use_uid=True, ssl=True)
    server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
```

P.S. I am not sure whether this question is related more to general python/Django rather than IMAP. So if I am missing something, please give a hint on this, I'll edit the question in a timely manner.

Comment: Look into [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). Storing the passwords in plain text in a third-party server (or any server, but even worse in a server you don't control) is a bad idea.